# Why Grid-column not working in @media query

Tags: media-queries, css-grid, grid-layout

I’ve a `12 column grid layout` and few grid items from `grid-column` 3 / 7 and 9 / 12 etc.
All default layout looks awesome.

But when I use `grid-column= 2 / -2`  inside a `@media` query, it does not work.
I tried to change the color through media query, just to confirm the if its working.
Color is changed but `grid-column` clause is not working.

```
footer > div {
    grid-column: 2 / -2;
    background-color: black;
    text-align: center;
}
```

### Question

I can acheive this by simply chanding the `display : block` but the I’ve to work with padding and margin, I want to understand what is wrong in `grid-column: 2 / -2` in `@media` query in css for a 12 column grid layout

### UPDATE - (More Info added)

Here is some sample code (all the 4 grid-items are fixed and have their own classes)

```
 .bottom-grid-container{
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(12, 1fr);
    grid-auto-rows: min-content;
    row-gap: 1vh;
    column-gap: 1vw;
  }
```

Here are my 3 grid-items, all are fixed items with different classes

```
.bottom-grid-container .first {
    grid-column: 3 / 7;
}
.bottom-grid-container .second {
    grid-column: 9 / 13;
}
.bottom-grid-container .third {
    grid-column: 1 / -1;
}
.bottom-grid-container .fourth {
    grid-column: 1 / -1;
}
```

Here is the media query.

```
@media  (max-width: 768px){
     .bottom-grid-container > div {
        background-color: black; /* just for debugging */
    }
     .bottom-grid-container .first {
        grid-column: 2 / -2;
        padding-top: 1rem;
        text-align: center;
    }
     .bottom-grid-container .second {
        grid-column: 2/ -2;
    }
}
```

### Update 2

I added another media query
the `.first` div is now going to 2/2 column when below 768px resolution. But the `.second` div gets changed at 959px to 8/13 from 9/13 but does not change to 2/2 when below 768px resolution.

```
@media (max-width: 959px){
   .bottom-grid-container .first {
        padding-top: 1rem;
    }
     .bottom-grid-container .second {
        grid-column: 8/ 13;
    }
   }
```

Comment: What does your @media query say?

Comment: You do have the <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"> on your html page? And the <!DOCTYPE html>

Comment: yes I have meta tag. grid are actually working everywhere. just in this sub section its failing. Its when I’m using in footer. . Pardon me I’m new in UI development and CSS. I think some content in my `.second` div creating the issue.. I’ll let you know when fix

Comment: so in other words, if the size is changed at `959px` breakpoint,  its not changing again at `768px`. My first div `.first` is changing to 2/2 because I did not change it at `959px` .

Comment: I got it... my second media query was creating problem...I changed the second one as a range query  `@media (min-width: 769px) and (max-width: 959px) `  instead of just  `@media (max-width: 959px)` now its all working as expected..

Comment: @Wayne but one strange thing is in my media query if I use  `.bottom-grid-container  > div  {     grid-column: 2 / -2; background-color: black; }` it changes color, so query works but grid doesn’t change. however if put specific class name of div as I mentioned in my question it work. Do you know why `.bottom-grid-container  > div` unable to change grid-column byt just the color ?

Comment: You can put the rule under the @media and see if the rule is working, I think that is were the problem is ... then once it is working put it back within the media rule ... If I'm not mistaken any overflow in a grid can make it appear to not be working correctly.